# Pattern of two letter groupings in CSS classes?

Tags: html, css

I can see some unusual patterns in the CSS classes on [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/animating-your-data-visualizations-like-a-boss-using-r-f94ae20843e3) page.

e.g.

```
<li id="ea69" class="nd ne cl aq nf b ng oe ni of nk og nm oh no oi nq ob oc od">
```

My first thoughts were perhaps they're base64 encoded or raw bits. But from comparing to actual data of those types, I don't think that's what they are.

My next thought was perhaps each item  (e.g. `nd`, `ne` etc) has its own definition, but I cannot spot them in the [page CSS](https://glyph.medium.com/css/e/sr/latin/e/ssr/latin/e/ssb/latin/m2.css)

What is going on and what are the strange CSS classes?

Comment: The CSS class definitions are right there in the page. As far as anyone other than the developer knows it could just be a simple optimization of code. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wnr9t72L/

Comment: That is usually the mark of obfuscated coding practices, partly to reduce page footprint and partly to thwart ad-blockers

Comment: @j08691 so they are. Is it some sort of convention (e.g. in some particular framework) to divide CSS classes into so many smaller components?

Comment: @fnostro interesting. This is all new to me. Do you know which technologies do this? Surely it's not manual!

Comment: Correct, it's probably not manually coded that way. I have no idea what software they're using to produce that.

Comment: No it's definitely automatic, part of the development process. It's along the same lines as coding CSS using SASS/SCSS but with 1 more step to do what you see there. There are a number of addons to dev environments that you can get to do this

Comment: @fnostro do you know if the process has a name? I am googling but the results are not related to this

Comment: try googling `obfuscate css classes` or `minify css classes`

Comment: @fnostro I have found a few but none where the classes look like 2 letter groupings. Examples [here](https://develoger.com/how-to-obfuscate-css-class-names-with-react-and-webpack-20e2b5c49cda), [minification](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351060/why-does-facebook-obfuscate-the-names-of-css-classes), and another [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870666/css-class-names-in-atlassians-jira-are-obfuscated). I will try to figure out which framework was used to build the site in my question to understand what tools may have been used